# How do I know the air-speed of my kart?

Tags: mario-kart-7

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47031/if-my-airspeed-and-groundspeed-are-equal-should-i-glide-long-or-glide-short-wh) makes reference to the air-speed of the kart, thus implying that there are different stats for air speed and ground speed, however I can't seem to find any indication of this in-game.

How do I know the air-speed of my kart?

Comment: There's a good chart here, I dunno where he got his data from and if it's available in-game, though: http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997822-mario-kart-7/faqs/63500

Comment: That chart is useless for actual comparison. Featherweight carts are speed '0'? Oh really? That must be a boring race.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart JohnoBoy posted is close, but uses the wrong units. [Super Mario Wiki's page on MK7](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_7) has all the values. Here's the short version for airspeed only:

1. All characters have a base airspeed of 4 (out of 6).
2. If you're using one of these karts, you get a -0.25 penalty:

   - Barrel Train
   - Blue Seven
   - Bolt Buggy
   - Bruiser/Growlster
   - Cact-X
   - Gold Body
   - Tiny Tug
   - Zucchini/Gherkin
3. If you're using one of these karts, you get a +0.5 bonus:

   - Birthday Girl/Royal Ribbon
   - Bumble V
   - Cloud 9
   - Egg 1
   - Pipe Frame
   - Soda Jet
4. If you're using one of these wheels, you get a +1 bonus:

   - Roller
   - Sponge
   - Wood
5. If you're using one of these gliders, you get a -1.5 penalty:

   - Paraglider/Parafoil
   - Swooper/Swoop
6. If you're using one of these gliders, you get a -3 penalty:

   - Flower Glider
   - Peach Parasol

Note that gliders have the strongest influence on airspeed - also note that the gliders with the biggest airspeed penalty have the biggest air handling bonus, so they're not total step-downs.

Comment: Is there anyway to figure out these values for yourself in-game though?

Comment: Pretty sure no, the stat bars shown in-game for split stats do some sort of merging calculation.